# Fastest way to read many inputs in PyPy3 and what is BytesIO doing here?

Tags: python-3.x, pypy

Recently I was working on a problem that required me to read many many lines of numbers (around 500,000).

Early on, I found that using input() was way too slow. Using stdin.readline() was much better. However, it still was not fast enough. I found that using the following code:

```
import io, os
input = io.BytesIO(os.read(0,os.fstat(0).st_size)).readline
```

and using input() in this manner improved the runtime. However, I don't actually understand how this code works. Reading the documentation for os.read, 0 in os.read(0, os.fstat(0).st_size) describes the file we are reading from. What file is 0 describing? Also, fstat describes the status of the file we are reading from but apparently that input is to denote the max number of bytes we are reading?

The code works but I want to understand what it is doing and why it is faster. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0` is the file descriptor for standard input. `os.fstat(0).st_size` will tell Python how many bytes are currently waiting in the standard input buffer. Then `os.read(0, ...)` will read that many bytes in bulk, again from standard input, producing a bytestring.

(As an additional note, `1` is the file descriptor of standard output, and `2` is standard error.)

Here's a demo:

```
echo "five" | python3 -c "import os; print(os.stat(0).st_size)"
# => 5
```

Python found four single-byte characters and a newline in the standard input buffer, and reported five bytes waiting to be read.

Bytestrings are not very convenient to work with if you want text — for one thing, they don't really understand the concept of "lines" — so `BytesIO` fakes an input stream with the passed bytestring, allowing you to `readline` from it. I am not 100% sure why this is faster, but my guesses are:

- Normal read is likely done character-wise, so that one can detect a line break and stop without reading too much; bulk read is more efficient (and finding newlines post-facto in memory is pretty fast)
- There is no encoding processing done this way